Why is httpx so much worse than aiohttp when facing high concurrent requests?
In the FastAPI web framework, why is httpx so much worse than aiohttp when facing high concurrent requests? They both reuse the same client instance.
test code
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
import requests
import httpx
import aiohttp

app = FastAPI(description="sync and async route func test")

aio_client = httpx.AsyncClient()
aio_session: aiohttp.ClientSession = None
req_session = requests.Session()


@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    global aio_session
    aio_session = aiohttp.ClientSession()


async def async_get(url):
    # async with aio_session.get(url) as resp:
    #     return resp

    resp = await aio_client.get(url)
    return resp


@app.get("/ping")
async def ping():
    return "pong"


@app.get("/async_route_func_demo")
async def async_route_func():
    url = "https://juejin.cn/"
    resp = await async_get(url)
    # print("resp", resp)
    return "async_route_func_demo"


@app.get("/async_route_use_sync_io_demo")
async def async_route_func():
    url = "https://juejin.cn/"
    resp = req_session.get(url)
    # print("resp", resp)
    return "async_route_func_demo"


@app.get("/sync_route_func_demo")
def sync_route_func():
    url = "https://juejin.cn/"
    resp = req_session.get(url)
    # print("resp", resp)
    return "sync_route_func_demo"


def main():
    uvicorn.run(app, log_level="warning")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

python version: Python 3.10.12
operating system: mac os  m1 pro
requirements
fastapi==0.101.0
uvicorn==0.23.2
requests==2.32.0
httpx==0.27.0

wrk test result
When I was testing the synchronous routing and asynchronous routing of fastapi, I found that the performance of httpx was not ideal. I don’t know if there is something wrong with my coding method. Could you please help me check it out.

Your code doesn't use aio_session, so you're not using aiohttp at all?

I assume the commented out code is the aiohttp test. I would assume they switch from one to the other in testing.

I've no idea why the difference, but why not just use aiohttp then?

You might find this answer, as well as  this answer and this answer helpful.

This is because aiohttp is lazy - in a good way.
Looking at this part of your code:
async def async_get(url):
    # async with aio_session.get(url) as resp:
    #     return resp

    resp = await aio_client.get(url)
    return resp

The commented lines 2&3 appear to be what you switch to for the aiohttp test. I can see the code is not awaiting the response, which is correct because you don't have to. The reason you don't have to is because it is only when you call a function on that response that it will actually do anything. For example if you tried to look at resp.json() or resp.text() then it would trigger the GET.
There's a good explanation of this in the aiohttp docs https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/http_request_lifecycle.html#why-is-aiohttp-client-api-that-way that compares aiohttp with requests (it doesn't mention httpx but it is the same theory) which I will repeat here:

When doing response.text in requests, you just read an attribute. The
call to .get() already preloaded and decoded the entire response
payload, in a blocking manner. aiohttp loads only the headers when
.get() is executed, letting you decide to pay the cost of loading the
body afterward, in a second asynchronous operation. Hence the await
response.text().

I would point out that even if you changed this script to call a function on the aiohttp response, your setup is not a valid test harness for comparing these libraries. The network I/O part of this code execution that goes from your local API service 127.0.0.1 out to the internet at https://juejin.cn/ and then back will be orders of magnitude slower that the library code functions, and that network transit will be extremely variable. Both libraries are very similar in performance if used equivalently, and I repeat, the network portion of this execution time is so much more significant than any micro-optimisations that you might be tempted to focus on.
Perhaps wrk is somewhat mitigating the network variability issue by measuring how many requests in 10 seconds, but I still advise you to not to place too much weight on the results.

I retested httpx and aiohttp and they are still quite different.You can pay attention to this issue of httpx.https://github.com/encode/httpx/issues/3215

Yes, I see even when you change it to return .text() it is still slow, and that github thread does point to some implementation issues with anyio vs asyncio. Glad to see a resolution that should appear in some future version of httpx as detailed in https://github.com/encode/httpx/issues/3215#issuecomment-2157885121 You should edit your answer below to include a note about that fix and the github thread and mark it as correct answer.

I retested httpx and aiohttp and they are still quite different.You can pay attention to this issue of httpx.https://github.com/encode/httpx/issues/3215
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
import requests
import httpx
import aiohttp

app = FastAPI(description="同步异步路由函数")

aio_client = httpx.AsyncClient()
aio_session: aiohttp.ClientSession = None
req_session = requests.Session()


@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    global aio_session
    aio_session = aiohttp.ClientSession()


async def async_httpx_get(url):
    resp = await aio_client.get(url)
    return resp


async def async_aiohttp_get(url):
    async with aio_session.get(url) as resp:
        return await resp.text()


@app.get("/ping")
async def ping():
    return "pong"


@app.get("/async_httpx_get")
async def async_route_func():
    url = "https://juejin.cn/"
    resp = await async_httpx_get(url)
    return resp.text


@app.get("/async_aiohttp_get")
async def async_route_func():
    url = "https://juejin.cn/"
    resp_text = await async_aiohttp_get(url)
    return resp_text


@app.get("/async_route_use_sync_io_demo")
async def async_route_func():
    url = "https://juejin.cn/"
    resp = req_session.get(url)
    return resp.text


@app.get("/sync_route_func_demo")
def sync_route_func():
    url = "https://juejin.cn/"
    resp = req_session.get(url)
    return resp.text


def main():
    uvicorn.run(app, log_level="warning")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

wrk test ret


If you also find httpx particularly slow (and it’s already heavily used in your codebase, making migration difficult), and you ended up here after Googling, here’s a simple conversion path:
class AiohttpTransport(httpx.AsyncBaseTransport):
    def __init__(self, session: typing.Optional[aiohttp.ClientSession] = None):
        self._session = session or aiohttp.ClientSession()
        self._closed = False

    async def handle_async_request(self, request: httpx.Request) -> httpx.Response:
        if self._closed:
            raise RuntimeError("Transport is closed")

        # 转换headers
        headers = dict(request.headers)
        
        # 准备请求参数
        method = request.method
        url = str(request.url)
        content = request.content
        
        async with self._session.request(
            method=method,
            url=url,
            headers=headers,
            data=content,
            allow_redirects=False,
        ) as aiohttp_response:
            # 读取响应内容
            content = await aiohttp_response.read()
            
            # 转换headers
            headers = [(k.lower(), v) for k, v in aiohttp_response.headers.items()]
            
            # 构建httpx.Response
            return httpx.Response(
                status_code=aiohttp_response.status,
                headers=headers,
                content=content,
                request=request
            )

    async def aclose(self):
        if not self._closed:
            self._closed = True
            await self._session.close()

Generally speaking, I found httpx slow in processing many concurrent requests. Here is my benchmark script and results:
import asyncio
import typing
import time
import aiohttp
from aiohttp import ClientSession
import httpx
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import statistics

ADDRESS = "https://www.baidu.com"

async def request_with_aiohttp(session):
    async with session.get(ADDRESS) as rsp:
        return await rsp.text()

async def request_with_httpx(client):
    rsp = await client.get(ADDRESS)
    return rsp.text

# 性能测试函数
async def benchmark_aiohttp(n):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        # make sure code is right
        print(await request_with_aiohttp(session))
        start = time.time()
        tasks = []
        for i in range(n):
            tasks.append(request_with_aiohttp(session))
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        return time.time() - start

async def benchmark_httpx(n):
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(
        timeout=httpx.Timeout(
            timeout=10,
        ),
    ) as client:
        # make sure code is right
        print(await request_with_httpx(client))

        start = time.time()
        tasks = []
        for i in range(n):
            tasks.append(request_with_httpx(client))
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        return time.time() - start
    
class AiohttpTransport(httpx.AsyncBaseTransport):
    def __init__(self, session: typing.Optional[aiohttp.ClientSession] = None):
        self._session = session or aiohttp.ClientSession()
        self._closed = False

    async def handle_async_request(self, request: httpx.Request) -> httpx.Response:
        if self._closed:
            raise RuntimeError("Transport is closed")

        # 转换headers
        headers = dict(request.headers)
        
        # 准备请求参数
        method = request.method
        url = str(request.url)
        content = request.content
        
        async with self._session.request(
            method=method,
            url=url,
            headers=headers,
            data=content,
            allow_redirects=False,
        ) as aiohttp_response:
            # 读取响应内容
            content = await aiohttp_response.read()
            
            # 转换headers
            headers = [(k.lower(), v) for k, v in aiohttp_response.headers.items()]
            
            # 构建httpx.Response
            return httpx.Response(
                status_code=aiohttp_response.status,
                headers=headers,
                content=content,
                request=request
            )

    async def aclose(self):
        if not self._closed:
            self._closed = True
            await self._session.close()


async def benchmark_httpx_with_aiohttp_transport(n):
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(
        timeout=httpx.Timeout(
            timeout=10,
        ),
        transport=AiohttpTransport(),
    ) as client:
        start = time.time()
        tasks = []
        for i in range(n):
            tasks.append(request_with_httpx(client))
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        return time.time() - start
    

async def run_benchmark(requests=1000, rounds=3):
    aiohttp_times = []
    httpx_times = []
    httpx_aio_times = []
    
    print(f"开始测试 {requests} 并发请求...")
    
    for i in range(rounds):
        print(f"\n第 {i+1} 轮测试:")
        
        # aiohttp 测试
        aiohttp_time = await benchmark_aiohttp(requests)
        aiohttp_times.append(aiohttp_time)
        print(f"aiohttp 耗时: {aiohttp_time:.2f} 秒")
        
        # 短暂暂停让系统冷却
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        
        # httpx 测试
        httpx_time = await benchmark_httpx(requests)
        httpx_times.append(httpx_time)
        print(f"httpx 耗时: {httpx_time:.2f} 秒")

        # 短暂暂停让系统冷却
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        
        # httpx 测试
        httpx_time = await benchmark_httpx_with_aiohttp_transport(requests)
        httpx_aio_times.append(httpx_time)
        print(f"httpx (aiohttp transport) 耗时: {httpx_time:.2f} 秒")
    
    print("\n测试结果汇总:")
    print(f"aiohttp 平均耗时: {statistics.mean(aiohttp_times):.2f} 秒")
    print(f"httpx 平均耗时: {statistics.mean(httpx_times):.2f} 秒")
    print(f"httpx 平均耗时: {statistics.mean(httpx_aio_times):.2f} 秒")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # 运行基准测试
    asyncio.run(run_benchmark(512))

Results:

aiohttp: 0.49s
httpx: 1.51s
httpx with aiohttp transport: 0.51s

